# updating javascript with xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization, xmlhttprequest

I was hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I would like to update a Google chart with xmlhttp, my script is here:

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <div id="myDiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
          ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
          ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
          ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
          ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
          ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
          ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data,
                 {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                  width:600, height:400,
                  hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
            );
      }




    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    ;
    </script>
    </div>

    <script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","UpdateGraph.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>



<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Below here is the php file (UpdateGraph.php) that I would like to update my content with, my intent is that a second graph would show up.  The way it currently works is it brings in the space to show another graph as well as a button I created in case it wouldn't "redraw" automatically.  When I remove the script tags from the UpdateGraph.php file then only text shows up in the area I would expect the new graph to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization2() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
          ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
          ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
          ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
          ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
          ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
          ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization2')).
            draw(data,
                 {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                  width:600, height:400,
                  hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
            );
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization2)
</script>
<button onclick="drawVisualization2()">Redraw 2nd Graph</button>
<div id="visualization2" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

I have no problems bringing in text but I am confused why I am not able to bring in new javascript or update javascript.  (btw the code in UpdateGraph.php works just fine when it is copied and pasted into the line that currently contains "div id="myDiv")

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing script tags in innerHTML assignments would be a security threat. Suppose that the data you were bringing down was user-supplied content provided in a form, and this was loaded by another user. User Bob could insert a script tag into the form, which would load malicious code from server X. User Charlie loads up a page with the specified content, and that malicious code runs. This is a form of cross-site scripting, and it's not surprising that your browser might be disabling this when using the innerHTML assignment. No guarantee that every browser would do this, however.

Here's more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML#Security_consideration

That said, there are two simpler ways to do what you want that *will* work. I recommend the first one as the best way:

1) Move the majority of your script, but not the update details, into a function that is loaded, but not necessarily run, with the page. Instead of retrieving the whole script text via xmlhttp, just return the data itself in some easy to parse format (such as JSON), and then just pass that data as arguments to a call to your update function

2) If you absolutely need to pass function calls, then you don't even need xmlhttp. Just dynamically create a script tag in the DOM, and point it's source to a PHP page which generates the script. The script will be loaded as soon as the script tag is added.

Comment: Thank you for your help, with your suggestion I followed what was outlined here and was successful:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example